# Creating a shape with particles

Tags: three.js

I want to create a shape say circle using the particle System in three.js. I checked some of the stuff in which they use ParticleCanvasMaterial and Texture(program: function) but that stuff is no longer supported . I went through co-ordinate system and tried to set values of pX, pY but it didn't work, well yeah here is my code any help will be appreciated..

Thanks

```
            var scene, camera, renderer;
            var controls, guiControls, datGUI;
            var spotLight, texture;
            var particleCount = 1800;
            var particles, pMaterial, particleSystem;
            var win_h = $(document).height();
            var win_w = $(document).width();

            function init() {

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setClearColor(0xB0C5E6);
                renderer.setSize( win_w, win_h );
                renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
                renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;

                controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
                controls.addEventListener('change', render);

                var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
                canvas.width = 100;
                canvas.height = 100;

                var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
                context.beginPath();
                context.arc( 0, 0, 1, 0,  Math.PI * 2, true );
                context.fill();

                particles = new THREE.Geometry();
                texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('ry.png');
                pMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
                    color: 0xB0C5E6,
                    size: 6,
                    map: texture,
                    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
                    transparent: true

                });


                for (var p = 0; p < particleCount; p++) {
                    var pX = (p * win_w )/ particleCount ;
                    var pY = 5;
                    var pZ = Math.random() * 500 - 750;
                    particle = new THREE.Vector3(pX, pY, pZ);



                    particles.vertices.push(particle);
                }

                particleSystem = new THREE.Points( particles, pMaterial );

                $('#webGL-con').append( renderer.domElement );

                scene.add(particleSystem);

            }


            function render() {

                requestAnimationFrame(render);

            }  

            function animate() {

                render();
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
                controls.update();
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            }

            init();
            animate();
```

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. Are you trying to use a circle as the particle texture, or are you trying to distribute the particles in a circle? If the latter, then you'll want to look into the "parametric equation for a circle" ... in which case you should be able to figure out how to position the particles in the shape of a circle/arc. You could also use a EllipseCurve to get the vertices generated for you.

Comment: Well, let's say I have 1000 particles I have to form a circle or triangle with that particles, something like [link](http://william.hoza.us/text/?t=Hello) @msu

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you just want to set particles in a circle, then it's rather easy. for a circle set on xz plane you use these:

```
var ratio = steps/(Math.PI*2)
for (var i = 0; i < steps; i ++ ) {
  var x = basePoint.x + radius * Math.cos(i/ratio);
  var y = basePoint.y;
  var z = basePoint.z + radius * Math.sin(i/ratio));
  particles.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x,y,z));
}
```

basePoint in this case is an a vector describing the center of the circle (like THREE.Vector3 for instance, or any object with keys x,y,z). ratio is used to define the density of (or rather distance between) points and steps is the number of particles you want set. If you want a different shape, you're going to have to figure out how to draw them in a loop - take a look at mathematical functions, they'll help you out with that.

Comment: steps here refers to no. of particles rigth? I tried, not exactly same but I got the basic idea...tq.

Comment: try now, I seem to have made an error there. I was actually just working on exactly the same thing and I just copypasted my solution, not realizing it'll only work for specific cases. and yeah, steps refers to the number of particles